# Rails documentation from rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

is that a way where i can search the API documentation for a method from the rails console? E.g. the method arguments, returning object, etc

Comment: No such animal. You can, however, use `rdoc` to generate a local copy of the Rails documentation, which you can browse/search via browser.

Comment: yes. ri is the one i am looking for. it is not rails console.

Comment: It's surprising that after all these years no one has made one. (that works in the console)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not rails console, but it is "ri" in console. This is what i am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

From irb (it might also work in rails console), you can do

```rb
require 'pry'
pry
require 'pry-doc'
? File.link # Shows documentation for File.link method, replace 
# with whatever method you want

From: file.c (C Method):
Owner: #<Class:File>
Visibility: public
Signature: link(arg1, arg2)
Number of lines: 20

Creates a new name for an existing file using a hard link. Will not
overwrite new_name if it already exists (raising a subclass
of SystemCallError). Not available on all platforms.

   File.link("testfile", ".testfile")   #=> 0
   IO.readlines(".testfile")[0]         #=> "This is line one\n"

static VALUE
rb_file_s_link(VALUE klass, VALUE from, VALUE to)
{
    FilePathValue(from);
    FilePathValue(to);
    from = rb_str_encode_ospath(from);
    to = rb_str_encode_ospath(to);

    if (link(StringValueCStr(from), StringValueCStr(to)) < 0) {
    sys_fail2(from, to);
    }
    return INT2FIX(0);
}
```

Note you'll need pry and pry-doc installed:

```
gem install pry
gem install pry-doc
```

Comment: Confirming that it does also work in rails console.